# Desktop Application form event

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Do we have any event when we click in the form body under desktop application?

> I need to set focus for hidden text-box whenever user click anywhere
>   in the form page body. For now, whenever user click anywhere in the
>   form body, focus of hidden text-box get lost.

I am aware about form activation event but that is not fulfilling the purpose.

Code as follow:-

```
this.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Form_Click);

private void Form_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    textBox.Focus();
}
```

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Does `Click` not fulfil the need?

Comment: Is this WPF? WinForms?

Comment: [Form click event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @vesan it's a win form

Comment: @Ben Yes you are right, but it's not getting fire.

Comment: Can you post some code? If it's not working the way you expect it to, it's likely because you're missing a step somewhere :)

Comment: @Ben i have added code. Pls check

Comment: Ok, so to my understanding - when you click on the form, then hidden textbox gains focus? Is that's what is happening/what you want to happen?

Comment: I would suggest you to first check if  control.CanFocus is true before you employ control.Focus! See when you can focus on a control [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Ben Right it's should get focus but it's not happening. but i guess, i found the reason actually form has so many controls and containers. when user click on other parts means containers or control, texbox not gaining the focus. For that i guess i need to use click event of all controls for gaining focus.

Comment: Ok, well just to clarify - `textBox` is actually the name of the textbox you want to focus on? Also, I'm not sure if you *can* focus on an invisible control, but as @Rahul suggested, you can check if `textbox.CanFocus()` first.

Comment: @Ben We can focus hidden textbox. Actually i was referring textbox as dummy ID.

Comment: No, an invisible TextBox cannot get the focus.  You would have to make it visible but give it a location that is not on the form: `textBox.Location = new Point(-120, -120);`